# Texture Not Applied To 2D Geometry

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a very simple program to apply a texture to a triangle created using OpenGL. Here is the code. The code compiles and runs smoothly but **I don't see the texture applied**. What am I doing wrong? All the necessary headers are added and this is the fully working code :

```
// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Shaders
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);  
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    // Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Left  
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // Right 
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // Top   
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs)

                          // Load and create a texture 
    GLuint texture1;
    // ====================
    // Texture 1
    // ====================
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); // All upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on our texture object
                                            // Set our texture parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // Set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // Set texture filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // Load, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width_t, height_t;
    unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("tex.jpg", &width_t, &height_t, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width_t, height_t, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    SOIL_free_image_data(image);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); // Unbind texture when done, so we won't accidentily mess up our texture.

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Bind Textures using texture units
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

        // Draw our first triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

The `tex.jpg` file is located directly under the project.

Comment: Where are you setting the color to the color of the texture in the fragment shader using it's uv's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your shaders and seeing how you are calling them, you have no in and outs for the UV coordinates, and from your vertices I am not seeing any UV coordinates being applied in order to see the texture on your surface, you need a vertex shader that will pass the UV data to your fragment shader, and in order for your vertex shader to do that your vertices first need to have UV's assigned to them.

See: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/

This will show you how to sample the texture in your Fragment shader to apply the color of the texture.